# Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed - dynamic table names, loops, inter-worksheet searching

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, worksheet

I keep running into  `Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed`.

In a worksheet called "Receiving" I have a table (the table is the only thing in the worksheet) that has a dynamic name (the name of the table changes from time to time) so I change the name to 'invoiceTable' at the beginning of the subroutine. Basically, I want to loop through the rows of invoiceTable and modify data in other worksheets according to the data in the table.

The 1st column in invoiceTable is called 'Frame' and the 5th is called 'Quantity Received'. I am trying to loop through invoiceTable and update data in a worksheet called 'Inventory Management' according to the Frames listed in invoiceTable. For each frame in invoiceTable I would like to take the 'Quantity Received' and add it to column T of 'Inventory Management' at the index of the specific Frame.

Similarly, I would like to take the value from invoiceTable under the heading 'Unit Price' and update the value in column F of 'Inventory Management' with the most recent purchase price for each Frame in invoiceTable.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name = "invoiceTable"

For row = 1 To Range("invoiceTable").Rows.Count
    If Range("invoiceTable[Frame]")(row).Value <> 0 Then
        Dim frame As String
        Dim purchQ As Integer
        Dim price As Long

        frame = Range("invoiceTable[Frame]")(row).Value
        price = Range("invoiceTable[Unit Price]")(row).Value
        purchQ = Range("invoiceTable[Quantity Received]")(row).Value

        Sheets("Inventory Management").Select
        Range("=OFFSET('Inventory Management'!F5,MATCH(frame,'Inventory Management'!B6:B41,0),0)").Value = price
        Range("=OFFSET('Inventory Management'!T5,MATCH(frame,'Inventory Management'!B6:B41,0),0)").Value = Range("=OFFSET('Inventory Management'!T5,MATCH(frame,'Inventory Management'!B6:B41,0),0)").Value + purchQ
        Sheets("Receiving").Select
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Qualify your ranges if you're working with multiple sheets such as `Range("invoiceTable").Rows.Count`

Comment: At which line does the error trigger?

Comment: That is the most convoluted use of the Range object I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in place of the 4 lines dealing with the Inventory Management sheet:

```
With Worksheets("Inventory Management")
    Dim FindFrame As Range
    Set FindFrame = .Range("B6:B41").Find(frame)
    If Not FindFrame Is Nothing Then
        .Cells(FindFrame.Row, 6) = Price
        .Cells(FindFrame.Row, 20) = .Cells(FindFrame.Row, 20) + purchq
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thanks! One issue though: the if-statement never executes because FindFrame = .Range("B6:B41").Find(frame) always seems to return Nothing, even when 'frame' is exactly the same as one of the items in Range("B6:B:41")